# Dropbox API returning http 500 status instead of http 400 status for a non-existant user in a team

Tags: dropbox-api

Starting at around 21:00 PM GMT today , when we query for a user which doesn't exist in dropbox team, we are receiving an http 500 status with internal error message. In comparison earlier we use to receive http 400 message with message that user doesn't exist in team.

Has something regressed at dropbox end, or is this change intentional and hence we should consider http 500 internal error as equivalent to user not found?

For example RESPONSE#1 is what we expected as valid behavior , while RESPONSE#2 is what we are receiving currently

RESPONSE#1
   Resource: https://api.dropbox.com/1/idm/get_profile?email=dummy@authentication.test
   Operation: GET
   Headers: Authorization: Bearer XXX
   Content Type: 
   Data: 
%% Time: 08/28/2014 17:06:51 GMT

Message: The remote server returned an error: (**400) Bad Request. Web Response: {"error": "User not** on this team"} ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

RESPONSE#2
   Resource: https://api.dropbox.com/1/idm/get_profile?email=dummy@authentication.test
   Operation: GET
   Headers: Authorization: Bearer XXX
   Content Type: 
   Data: 
Time: 08/28/2014 22:40:29

**(500) Internal Server Error. Web Response: {"error": "Internal Server Error"}** ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Thanks
Somesh

Comment: Please open a Dropbox API support ticket: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact.

Comment: I am trying to file a ticket, but I upon submitting my information I get http 500 error. "Error (500)
Something went wrong. Don't worry, your files are still safe and the Dropboxers have been notified. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home. "

Comment: Thanks for the reports! We're aware of and are working on fixing both issues.

Comment: Thanks! The issue seems to be fixed now.